# Flex Number.toFixed not giving expected result

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, numerical-methods, number-formatting

I have a function that gets a numeric value (as Object) and returns a well formatted representation of that number. Because we can get very small numbers, in the process we use the Number object of flex. this is part of the code:

```
var numericValue:Number = Number(value.toString());
var fixed:String = numericValue.toFixed(precision);
```

This is the problem: there are situations that the numeric value is in the form of
`5.684341886080802e-14` 
because we want to represent these numbers as `0` we use the above code. In this specific case, where precision is 0 we get an odd result

```
Initial Values:
value = 5.684341886080802e-14
percision = 0

Operation on values:
var numericValue:Number = Number(value.toString());
var fixed:String = numericValue.toFixed(precision); 

Result:
fix = "1."
```

Why is this?
(BTW - on other numbers in the representataion of `X.XXXXXXe-YY` with percision bigger than 0 we get the correct result of 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Flash Player ([FP-5141](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-5141)). It has been around for quite a while. The bug report says it is fixed, but it is not as of Flash Player 11.5.